# What's the best way to render a lot of text with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, text, rendering

I work on a software who need to print a lot of texts on the screen, around 200 to 400 strings and a lot unique character (some objects are represented by a character), the software is already drawing a lot of things using OpenGL.
I already worked around with text rendering and I'm able to render text, but drawing more than 200 string using 200 draw call lead in a performance issue.

The software draw only in 2D.

It's important to notice that I the software run on 32bit computer with old graphics card, I can't use a more recent version of OpenGL than 2.0.

What would be the best options from your opinion?

1. Render everything in one draw call per font, using one big buffer with all information.
2. Render each string in a texture and then make one draw call for every string. (the text don't change a lot, every seconds max)
3. Any other idea?

Comment: 200 to 400 strings should not cause performance issues, something like 1000 page pdf may.

Comment: It's really old computer. The previous version of the software was using Qt to render the same scene. The CPU was going crazy to 65%. That's why I try to find the best approach

Comment: I guess you should investigate the source of the performance issues first. Use a profiler and check which part of the code consumes more time. Something like `std::map<GLText, std::list<size_t>>` seems cheesy. That's certainly not how texture atlas is meant to be implemented.

Comment: Yes I know. That's why I'm here. We profiled the software, the problem is that Qt use one drawcall for each element on the screen. All the CPU time is spent on looking for change and drawing

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think my way of rendering the text is anywhere close to standard, I prerendered the font into one giant glyph map, and stored the metadata (the location of glyphs) into a ssbo buffer (that stores an array of glyphs data except the bitmap and the advance). After that, when I need to render a bunch of text, I converted the charcodes to an array of glyph IDs. Then by looping over it and only passing over a vec2 position and a hint glyph Id per char, I turned points to a rectangle in the geometry shader by reading data in the ssbo, passing along the texture coordinate to fragment shaders.

This method is so fast that it can easily render 10000s of text. It also allows fast switching of font sets, and able to support any unicode char as long as the font has the glyph.

Answer (score 0):

From what I learned, the standard approach would be to make a font atlas texture. This is the place where you can rasterize the glyphs to, and save the uv coordinates of the rasterized glyphs into a lookup table. Then batch the vertices and draw all of the text in one draw call by using a single texture (your atlas) and having one buffer for all vertex positions.

All of the fonts and character sizes can be written to the same atlas, provided that you make a large enough texture. You could also probably use a second atlas texture for the unique characters.

Comment: Yes, the atlas is a must have, I already draw the text using it. 
The point is that is not easy to maintain a buffer with all the data of each character of each string. As a string could grow and reduce, change a letters, colors.. ect. 
My actual approach is to have a std::map<GLText, std::list<size_t>> where the list is a list of indices where each character data of the given string are stocked in the buffer.
Using instancing it would be easy, but opengl 2 does not have it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're unable to have a single buffer for all the vertices of your texts?

Comment: No I could. But it's not easy, or I don't know how to do it well.
It would be easy if I rebuild the buffer each frame, but then it would be cpu expensive.
By vertices you mean, each vertex of the square used to render the character or just it's position ?

Comment: I can't be sure about your case but I have a hunch that rebuilding one vertex buffer for ~400 strings should be less of a performance hit compared to 400 draw calls.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenGl does not have any support to render fonts on screen , it is left to the programmer to define a system.

Freetype is a good Library to render fonts.

https://www.freetype.org/

You can render Font Texture to Quads or Make Font Atlas and than render them to Quads

Generally 200 strings should not be challenging but you can check techniques like signed distance fields.

This is a good tutorial to render fonts in opengl.

https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering